# A question related to completely integrable nonsingular distributions

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

Let a nonsingular distribution $\Delta$ on $D\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, generated by $f_1,\dots,f_k:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$, be completely integrable, i.e., for each $x_0\in D$, there exists a neighborhood $N$ of $x_0$ and $n-k$ real-valued smooth functions $h_1(x),\dots,h_{n-k}(x)$ such that
\begin{equation*}
dh_j(x)f_i(x) = 0,\quad \forall 1\le i\le k\text{ and }1\le j\le n-k
\end{equation*}
and the row vectors $dh_1(x),\dots,dh_{n-k}(x)$ are linearly independent for all $x\in D$ where $dh = \partial h/\partial x$.
Let $g_1,\dots,g_r$ with $r<n-k$ be smooth real-valued functions on $D$ satisfying that
\begin{equation*}
dg_j(x)f_i(x) = 0,\quad \forall 1\le i\le k\text{ and }1\le j\le r,
\end{equation*}
$dg_1(x),\dots,dg_r(x)$ are linearly independent, and $dg_1(x),\dots,dg_r(x)\in\mathrm{span}\{dh_1(x),\dots,dh_{n-k}(x)\}$ for all $x\in D$.
My question is that do there always exist smooth real-valued functions $g_{r+1}(x),\dots,g_{n-k}(x)$ satisfying that
\begin{equation*}
dg_j(x)f_i(x) = 0,\quad \forall 1\le i\le k\text{ and }1\le j\le n-k,
\end{equation*}
$dg_1(x),\dots,dg_{n-k}(x)$ are linearly independent, and $dg_1(x),\dots,dg_{n-k}(x)\in\mathrm{span}\{dh_1(x),\dots,dh_{n-k}(x)\}$ for all $x\in D$?
If it is true, would you give me any reference or a hint on how to prove it?
I was trying to prove it by writing $dg_j(x)$ as a linear combination of $dh_1(x),\dots,dh_{n-k}(x)$ but it didn't go well...

Comment: Can you remove all the derivatives and vector fields from this question and make it just a simple linear algebra question? Once you've done that, can you adapt it to the question about functions?

Comment: @TedShifrin Unfortunately, I can't remove derivatives because that is the core part of this question. This question is about the existence of the solution of the differential equations that satisfies a certain condition.

Comment: Since you didn’t want to think about what I suggested, I’ll give it away. How do you choose $n-k-r$ of the functions $h_i$ to accomplish this?

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for your suggestion. Actually, that was the way my book said and I couldn't understand it. If I choose some of $h_i$, then how can we guarantee that the derivatives are linearly independent? So, I was trying to write $dg_j$ as a linear combination of $dh_i$ but in this case I cannot guarantee integrability of $dg_j$. This is the point I am stuck...

Comment: I’m back to my original suggestion. Why don’t you stop being stubborn and think about the linear algebra question? That’s entirely what this is.

Comment: @TedShifrin I realized that my book requires that the problem holds locally. Thus, I only need to show that for each $x_0\in D$ there is a neighborhood $N$ of $x_0$ such that $n-k-r$ functions of $h_i$ can be chosen to satisfy the properties. Then, it becomes a simple linear algebra problem because I can arbitrarily reduce $N$ to make derivatives linearly independent. I am not sure if it is what you meant but the problem looks solved. Thanks for your comments and sorry for being stubborn.